# minimising code in if condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a code

```
if(!fs.existSync(path.join(data,file,path)){
 fs.mkdirSync(path.join(data,file,path));
}


if(!fs.existSync(path.join(another,file)){
 fs.mkdirSync(path.join(another,file));
}


if(!fs.existSync(path.join(new,file,temp,path)){
 fs.mkdirSync(path.join(new,file,temp,path));
}
```

so i have to write `path.join(data,file,path), path.join(new,file), path.join(another,file,temp,path)` 2 times is there any way i can minimize this line?
or should i leave this like this only ?

or i put this in one Array and then mkdir

```
array= 
[path.join(data,file,path),
 path.join(new,file), 
 path.join(another,file,temp,path)
]
if(fs.existSync(array.include){
fs.mkdirSync(array.include)
}
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like this so you don't repeat code

```
function mkdir(data,file,p){
    var dir = path.join(data,file,p);
    if(!fs.existSync(dir)
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

mkdir(data,file,path);
mkdir(another,file,path);
mkdir(yetanother,file,path);
```

Using an array you could do this

```
var arr = [path.join(data,file,p), path.join(another,file,p)];

function mkdir(p){
    if(!fs.existSync(p)
        fs.mkdirSync(p);
}

arr.forEach(mkdir);
```

Comment: by using array can it be possible ? @Molda

Comment: No, first param to `fs.existSync` must be a string so passing in a `array.include` is wrong. just read the docs https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path

Comment: @Vikas i added an array example

Comment: actually already i am writing this in one function creating another function is this a good idea ?

Comment: having modularity is good idea. But creating too much of modular code is bad. Yes, you can have seperate function, if you can have common logic inside that function, which would be much easier to maintain

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating another function within a function. Especially because Array.forEach requires a function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any scope of improvement unless you want to write a new method to check the fs.existSync() {which is not a good idea}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
var array =[another , new, data];

array.forEach(element =>{
  if(!fs.existSync(path.join(element,file,path))
      fs.mkdirSync(path.join(element,file,path));

});
```